# SD Card recognized as MMC not SDX

Tags: sd-card

My SD card if not recognized as dev/sdX, instead it is recognised as dev/mmcblk0, which I understand is okay. The problem is that I'm trying to put an Angstrom image to my beaglebone and according to the instruction,

```
xz -dkc Angstrom-Cloud9-IDE-eglibc-ipk-v2011.10-core-beaglebone-r0.img.xz > /dev/sdX
```

I'm supposed to find an sdX that represents my SD card. I'm new to this so I'm not sure what's wrong. Any advise is appreciated.

Comment: What does `sudo fdisk -l` give you?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you unmount the card using `sudo umount /dev/mmcblk0`, and you can write the image file to `/dev/mmcxxxx` just like you would a using `/dev/sdx`

Comment: Thanks Bert for the reply,

Thats the result for sudo fdisk -l

I posted what counts cause its too big

Disk /dev/mmcblk0: 7822 MB, 7822376960 bytes
4 heads, 16 sectors/track, 238720 cylinders, total 15278080 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

        Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/mmcblk0p1   *          63      144584       72261    c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/mmcblk0p2          147456     7127039     3489792   83  Linux

Comment: The px at the end of those stands for partition - you want to leave that part off when you're writing the image